# Edge window is solid blue (not BSOD)

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-edge

I'm typing this in a Microsoft Edge 40.15063.0.0 window, but I have another Edge Window on my Windows 10 15063.483 laptop that looks solid blue except for the minimize, maximize and close in the upper right hand corner.

This has been happening to me a lot recently.  If I try to click the full screen icons on the frozen Edge to toggle between full-screen and windowed the true contents of the browser will flash for a split second, then it goes back to solid blue.  Does anyone else get this?  Any fix?

Comment: You might want to update your installation.  You are using a build that was released last July.

Comment: Chrome or Firefox should fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure out a fix for the Window in question, but maybe someone will figure out a better one.  I clicked on the button that toggles between full screen and windowed mode and put it on windowed mode, it was still a solid blue screen.  I then resized the window and it looked normal again. It had two opened tabs.